# Replace multiple occurences of character after zero-length assertion

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to replace every `_` with a `-` on lines starting with `#| label:`  using PCRE2 regex within my text editor.

Example:

```
#| label: my_chunk_label
my_function_name <- function(x)
```

Should become:

```
#| label: my-chunk-label
my_function_name <- function(x)
```

In contrast to .NET regex, where one could substitute `(?<=^#\| label: .+)_` with `-` [(regex101 example)](https://regex101.com/r/8fdWdP/1), PCRE2 does not support infinite lookbehind so the regex is invalid. So far, the only way I found was to repeatedly substitute `^#[^_]+\K_` with `-` [(regex101 example)](https://regex101.com/r/o7B4n2/1) but I was curious if there is a single-pass solution.

Comment: Also an idea to [skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) the other lines: [`^(?!#\| label:).+(*SKIP)(*F)|_`](https://regex101.com/r/5uujbQ/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble That is also nice :-)

Comment: @bobblebubble interesting and quite simple to understand (as well as efficient). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks jkd and 4th bird! I added this as an alternative. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using pcre, you could make use of `\G` and `\K`

Then in the replacement use `-`

```
(?:^#\|\h+label:\h+|\G(?!^))[^\r\n_]*\K_
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `^#\|\h+label:\h+` Match the pattern that should be at the start of the string, where `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace character
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `[^\r\n_]*` Match optional characters except for newlines or `_`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `_` Match the underscore

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nLoSe1/1)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the perfect and fast reply. I had not yet found out about the `\G` anchor.

Comment: first `|`should be escaped, otherwise great answer

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul You are right, I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative idea is to use PCRE verbs [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to skip the lines that you don't want.

```
^(?!#\| label:).+(*SKIP)(*F)|_
```

It's also related to [The Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). On the left side of the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) lines that *don't* start with `#| label` get identified by use of a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), matched by `.+` and skipped - no replacment wanted in these lines. On the right side matching is done in the remaining lines.

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5uujbQ/1) (replace with whatever you like - [add variable space if needed](https://regex101.com/r/O35U5M/1))